# More efficient text-based loading bar

Tags: python

I am making a program that has a "loading bar" but I can't figure out how to make the code shorter. This might be a simple fix for all I know, but for the life of me, I just can't figure it out. Here is what I have tried to do so far:

```
def ldbar():
    print "Load: 1%"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system('clear')
    print "Load: 2%"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system('clear')
    print "Load: 3%"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system('clear')
    print "Load: 4%"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system('clear')
    print "Load: 5%"
    #So on and so forth up to 100%

ldbar()
```

So, like I said, is there anyway I can make this shorter?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why, I am asking how to do something, I'm not asking for review of my code. If there are some things about my question that suggest that, please, edit my question.

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy you are asking how to improve working code - that is off-topic here, on-topic at Code Review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def ldbar():
    for i in range(1, 100):
        print "Load: {}%\r".format(i),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)

ldbar()
```

It uses a [`for`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) loop to avoid having the same code over and over again. In the print statement I use `\r` which moves the cursor to the front of the line, allowing it to be overwriten which is why `sys.stdout.flush` is used to make sure the output is printed without a newline (notice the comma at the end of the print statement which says that a newline should not be printed).

For Python 3 you would use this (but I think you're using python 2):

```
def ldbar():
    for i in range(1, 100):
        print("Load: {}%\r".format(i), end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)

ldbar()
```

Comment: Also since I'm running this program from a Linux terminal, could I just use __os.system('clear')__ instead of __sys.stdout.flush()__ ?

Comment: You can, but that's not fully cross-platform and would be slower because it requires creating a new process.

Comment: It also deletes anything in the terminal, which may or may not be what you want. ``flush`` simply writes anything in the ``stdout`` buffer immediately instead of waiting for 'free time'.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice version using a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

@contextmanager
def scoped_progress_bar(num_steps, message):
    class Stepper(object):
        '''
        Helper class that does the work of actually advancing the progress bar message
        '''
        def __init__(self, num_steps, message):
            self.current_step = 0.0
            self.num_steps    = num_steps
            self.message      = message

        def step(self, steps = 1.0):
            self.current_step += steps
            sys.stdout.write('\r{}:{}%'.format(message, (self.current_step/self.num_steps)*100))
            sys.stdout.flush()


    stepper = Stepper(num_steps, message) # This is where we actually create the progress bar
    yield stepper.step                    # This is where we do the yield secret sauce to let the user step the bar.
    # Finally when the context block exits we wind up back here, and advance the bar to 100% if we need to
    if stepper.current_step < stepper.num_steps:
        stepper.step(stepper.num_steps - stepper.current_step)
```

The advantage of this method is that

1. You can specify an arbitrary number of steps
2. You can step an arbitrary number of steps
3. Even if you don't hit the end of the number of steps, the context manager will always print 100% at the end
4. You can specify an arbitrary message

Usage:

```
with scoped_progress_bar(10, 'loading') as step:
    for i in xrange(7):
        step()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Which prints:

```
loading: 10%
loading: 20%
...
loading: 70%
loading: 100%
```

It's likely a bit overkill for your situation, but thought I'd provide it just in case.

An important thing to note with all of these answers is that they assume you won't be printing out stuff during the process in which you're advancing the progress bar. Doing so will still work just fine, it just might not look like what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

First off, use the Progressbar module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar), it already does everything you'll ever want from a text-mode progress bar, and then some.

Now for a fix for your specific implementation, what you want to do is write a bar to stdout (or stderr) with no line return, then erase it, then draw it again. You do it like so:

```
import sys
import time

sys.stdout.write("0%")
# stdout is line-buffered and you didn't print a newline,
# so nothing will show up unless you explicitly call flush.
sys.stdout.flush()

time.sleep(2)

# Move the cursor back to the beginning of the line
# and overwrite the characters.
sys.stdout.write("\r1%")
sys.stdout.flush()

time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.write("\r2%")
sys.stdout.flush()

# etc.
```

But really, use progressbar.

Comment: I would use progressbar, but I'm working off a raspberry pi that's not connected to the interwebz.

Comment: Just wondering, if you can, could you give an example of how I could use the progressbar module to achieve what I am doing?